# Sanity/React Blog Failed to compile message

Tags: reactjs, blogs, sanity

I'm following the step by step instructions at

https://www.sanity.io/guides/build-your-first-blog-using-react#c46733c34d93

I'm getting the following error.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> './components/AllPosts.js' in '/Users/ablair/sanity-react/src'

Im using vs code. Below is a screenshot of the file structure and code for the AllPosts.js and OnePost.js.

[image: vscode screenshot]

I can't seem to figure out the problem here. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't submit screenshots for code examples. Use the editor

Comment: And how did you import it in app.js?

Comment: It seems to me @ABlair having an issues with specifying full path to the component.

Comment: Offtopic: Please use external services for uploading the images on the StackOverflow.Not sure about the rest folks, but images are small and blurry for me (4k resolution)